# Setting a CSS Id property inside ngOnInit not working in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I'm having a little issue with setting a property height.

In my ngOnInit method I have this code below. When I step through it I can see the value of the property change in the console, but there's no change on screen or in the debugger. I also tried running this inside AfterViewInit but that didn't seem to do anything as well.

FYI - If I create a button and trigger it manually on the page I can make the change, it just doesn't work inside ngOnInit.

Any any one tell me why or if I'm doing something incorrectly?

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  if (something) {
    document.getElementById('map-full').style.setProperty('height', 'calc(100vh - 57px)');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('map-full').style.setProperty('height', 'calc(100vh - 105px)');
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="map-full">
```

Comment: did you try ngAfterContentInit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work as is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hupjkb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

You can change the `if` on line 10 and observe the 'Start Editing..' text shift up and down when the 'map' `div` changes height.

But this is not the idiomatic way to achieve this in angular:

- you should avoid interacting with `document` and retrieving or manipulating the DOM in this manner.
- it is preferred to keep styling in CSS rather than inline

A more typical approach is to use CSS and class bindings:

**Template:**

```
<div id="map-full" [class.full-height]="fullHeight || null">Map</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div { 
  height: calc(100vh - 105px)
}
div.full-height { 
  height: calc(100vh - 57px)
}
```

**Component class:**

```
fullHeight = false;
```

Changing the value of `fullHeight` will apply or remove the class from the `div`, which will apply the relevant CSS.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gw4x8d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello2.component.ts

Comment: Thank you for this help on a Fri night!

Comment: No problem, Saturday evening for me :)

Comment: what country are you in?

Comment: Auckland New Zealand

Comment: Quick question. This solution works great if you're in the component where you need to set the property. I have a navbar at the top of the site where I'm doing something similar on a button click, but the property being set isn't in the navbar, it's in the component that was part of my OP. I'm using the .setProperty method in the navbar and it's working ok, should I try and change it and if so how would I change it? It seems like I'd need a service for this?

Comment: Yes you should change it, avoid `setProperty` and the other JS DOM functions full stop + you shouldn't change one components height from another - styling should be internal to each component. Yes use a service to effect this, if you get stuck post another question  and I'll look at it.

Comment: I think I got it from here, but you said "you shouldn't change one components height from another". FYI - just to give you a clear picture of what I'm doing and why I have it like this. I have a navbar with a collapsable bottom section that shows some options for the search bar in it. The navbar has a fixed top (bootstrap) so I've had to pad the top of each page with the height of the navbar (57px). In 3 of my pages I have a google map that's full height inside another container, this is the post above. When I open/collapse the navbar options I need to reset the height of the map on the page.

Comment: Maybe there's another, better, way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242168/discussion-between-wlf-and-user1186050).